# Call an action from a different controller (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this code line in a view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Resumen", "Preview", "Anuncio", new { idAnuncio = Model.AnuncioId })
```

When executing the view, the idAnuncio has a value. Also comment that this view has a Anuncio model.
So, when I click the above link "Resumen" calling an action "Preview" that is in "Anuncio" controller, it goes to "Preview" action that has as parameter:

```
public ActionResult Preview(Models.UploadFileModel model)
```

When the execution is in this action, the model parameter with value model.idAnuncio is 0. So I get an error when managing this variable.

How can I call an action from a View that has a model different of the action I call?

Thank youn in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add null as last params.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Resumen", "Preview", "Anuncio", new { idAnuncio = Model.AnuncioId }, null)
```

Comment: That's it. So, what's the difference? why that null parameter makes the code run ok?

Comment: @Levimatt, because function has overloading, so you used incorrect method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx